# TeamCity CI - Make custom build output folder

Tags: teamcity

I am trying to make script that is able to copy after successful build only certain files to custom output folder on TeamCity CI server that has been installed on windows 7 OS. Any suggestion on how to do this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3):

1. Remember that you sources are not built on TeamCity CI server machine - all builds are executed on Build Agents (which can be located on other hosts)
2. Best practice is to use TeamCity's own [artifact publishing feature](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Artifact)
3. Check some solutions described here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-1558
4. [Deployer plugin](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) can be useful